# Why highstock charts have two yAxis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

if you examine the number of Highstock yAxis objects there are two however for a standard bar chart there is one

I am a bit confused why the two yAxis objects and what they relate to, the existence of the two yAxes can be seen in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2N52H/1/) by adding the alert call

```
alert(chart.yAxis.length);
```

at line 93 just before the click handler

It also seems that when you add data series there are always 1 more yAxis than data series.

Comment: There's one for the chart and one for the navigator, which isn't present in Highcharts.

Comment: Thanks, do you know which one is which, is this documented anywhere? maybe you should submit this as answer

Comment: looks like yAxis[1] is for the navigator and yAxis[0] for the chart as the height is greater for  yAxis[0], this means that when extra Axes are added the chart yAxes will be [0] [2] [3] etc. a bit awkward!

Comment: Correct, except the navigator will always be the last index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple Highstock charts there will be two of each axis. The first one is for the chart, as usual, and the second one is for the navigator which comes with Highstock and appears below the chart.

- If you add more axis in the constructor options the navigator will be the last index in the `chart.xAxis` and `chart.yAxis` arrays.
- If you add more axis dynamically after creation (using `chart.addAxis`) they will be added to the end of the array, so navigator will remain at it's original index.

Settings for the navigator axis is usually set through `navigator.xAxis` and `navigator.yAxis`.

Comment: are you sure about it being the last index, I just added an extra axis and it is still in position 2

Comment: Hm. See the console here: http://jsfiddle.net/2N52H/70/ -- I've added two y-axis to the chart. The last index has `height: 40`, which should be the navigator. Did you find some other case?

Comment: I see your post. Could you add a JSFiddle example of this?

Comment: maybe its because I am adding the axis using the chart.addAxis function, I'll see if I can find a jsfiddle to modify

Comment: Oh, that sounds interesting. Yea, that could be it. Good find.

Comment: Good find! Updated to reflect differences with static and dynamic adding of axis.

Comment: I think you are wrong about the navigator.xAxis etc, seems the only way you can check if the yAxis is the navigator is by looking at its height (<=40)!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the yAxis height it seems that the second yAxis (yAxis[1]) is for the navigator window below the chart. So the chart yAxis relating to the data series are at yAxis[0], yAxis[2] yAxis[3] ... etc.

debugger output

```
line.plot.yAxis[0].height
229
line.plot.yAxis[1].height
40
line.plot.yAxis[2].height
229
```